# Checking for Empty Cells in Google Sheets using c# via Google Sheets API v4

Tags: c#, .net, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

This is code snippet. I have successfully connected to Google Sheets API v4 using C#. I found out that when a cell is blank or empty. I get this error: **System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index'**
 As you can see Input ID in cell E3 cell is blank/empty. I tried this in the code below to check once it is blank it gives value of zero, but still gives same error. What I want to achieve is once a cell is blank I give it value of zero or unknown?? Bear in mind if I put value in cell E3 code works fine, Just need to check for empty cells.  Reference from here https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/dotnet#further_reading  [image]

```
            int inputId = 0;
            foreach (var row in values)
            {

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
                command.Connection = ServerConnection;            // <== lacking
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.CommandText = "INSERT into [GoogleSheetsAPI].[dbo].[Followup Stage] ( [Timestamp], [Email Address], [Do You Want To Follow Up] ,[Is The Issue Resolved From Follow Up] ,[Input ID]) VALUES (@TimeStamp, @EmailAddress,  @DoYouWantToFollowUp,  @IsTheIssueResolvedFromFollowUp,  @InputID ) ";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeStamp", Convert.ToDateTime(row[0]));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAddress", Convert.ToString(row[1]));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DoYouWantToFollowUp", Convert.ToString(row[2]));
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsTheIssueResolvedFromFollowUp", Convert.ToString(row[3]));
 //checking for null   or if the cell is empty  still doesn't work this way??
                if (row[4] == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(row[4])))
                {
                    inputId = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    inputId = Convert.ToInt32(row[4]);
                }

                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InputID", inputId);


                try
                {
                    // ServerConnection.Open();
                    int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                catch (SqlException E)
                {
                    // error here
                    Console.Write(E.Message);
                    //   Console.ReadLine;
                }



            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing we have to understand is that Sheets API doesn't read "empty cells",. You can read that in [Read a single range grouped by column](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/reading):

> Empty trailing rows and columns are omitted from the response.

It may not be direct but that's what also the tests says. When I read an empty cell, I get the same error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

One workaround to this would be to write a placeholder for "empty cells" like what you did with "zero or unknown".

If that's not an option, you can also do an if-else like method to catch the error before it halts your program. To implement this, do something like:

example:

```
 for (i = 0; i < range.values.length; i++) {
        //IF NOT AN EMPTY CELL
        if(range.values[i][j]){

           console.log(range.values[i][i] + " is my value");
         //IF IT's AN EMPTY CELL
         }else{

            console.log("U N D E F I N E D");
            //your method to write to that cell
            writeToSheet();
         }         
  }
```

Hopefully this simple analogy helps you.

Comment: '       try
                    {
                        if (row[4].Equals(null) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(row[4])))
                        {
                            inputId = 0;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            inputId = Convert.ToInt32(row[4]);
                        }
                    }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                       Console.WriteLine( e.Message);
                    }
'

Comment: Yes Thank you, Your analogy worked. What I did was used to wrap the if else statement in a try block then once Empty trailing rows and columns throw an error, the catch block would handle the exception error....then the loop would continue processing the other remaining rows....I tested and its working fine

Comment: brilliant! ; ) you did it mate